# How to prove that $|f^\prime(z)|\leq 1+2 C r$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $W$ be class of function which are univalent and analytic in the unit disk of the form
$$
f(z)=z-\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k z^k
$$
$f\in W$ if and only if
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k \leq C
$$
with $a_k \geq 0,C\geq 0$.

How to show that $\forall f\in W,$ $|f(z)|\leq r+C r^2$ and $|f^\prime(z)|\leq 1+2 C r$ for $|z|=r\leq 1$?

For the first part I have
$|f(z)|\leq|z|+\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k |z|^k\leq|z|+|z|^2 \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k \leq r+Cr^2$

However, for the second part $|f^\prime(z)|\leq 1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty ka_k |z|^{k-1}\leq 1+|z| \sum_{k=2}^\infty ka_k=1+r \sum_{k=2}^\infty ka_k$

How to finish the second part?

Comment: What if $a_k=1/k^2$? In that case, $f'(z)$ is not bounded at $z=1$ whereas your claim would say it is.

Comment: @Gary, $f$ here belongs to a class called $W$ and each function in this class is bounded by these upper bounds.

Comment: This should be stated clearly in the question.

Comment: There is no $r$ in the condition for $f$ to be a member of $W$. Also $f$ may not be defined when $|z|=r=1$.

Comment: Being analytic on the unit disc does not mean that $f(z)$ is defined for $|z|=r=1$. Shouldn't $r<1$?

Comment: @Gary, in my notes it is $\leq$. Does $<$ prove the inequality for $f^\prime$?

Comment: Is $C$ the same for all $f$ or it can depend on $f$?

Comment: @Gary, the same for all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for $0<C< 1/2$ as the best we can say is $|f'(z)|\le 1 +|z|$ which of course implies the required result for $C \ge 1/2$, while of course the case $C=0$ is trivial as $f(z)=z$ then

Note that $f'(0)=1>0$ and $f'(r)$ real and non zero for $0<r<1$ means $f'(r)>0$ hence passing to $r\to 1$ we get $1-\sum_{k \ge 2}ka_k \ge 0$ so $|f'(z)| \le 1+\sum_{k \ge 2}ka_kr^{k-1} \le 1+r$ as $r^{k-1} \le r$ for $k \ge 2$

But $z-az^2-bz^N$ is univalent in the unit disc if $2a+Nb \le 1$ ( and $a,b \ge 0$ of course) by the triangle inequality as then $a|z+w| +b|z^{N-1}+z^{N-2}w+...+w^{N-1}| <1$ for $|z|,|w| <1$ and one clearly can solve $a+b=C, 2a+Nb=1$ in positive numbers  $a,b$ for $0<C <1/2$ and large $N$ ($b=\frac{(1-2C)}{N-2}>0$ and $Nb<1$ for large enough $N$ as $Nb_N \to 1-2C<1$)   which we can choose even and then $f'(-r) \to 1+2a+Nb =2$ as $r\to 1$ so one cannot have $f'(-r) \le 1+2Cr \le 1+2C$ for $r$ very close to $1$ and $C<1/2$